pass value generated with RUN command to ENV
I need to download an oracle client, put it in a folder, and set the path to this folder as an environment variabile. So far I got here:
ENV ORACLE_DRIVER_PATH=test_value
RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip -P /opt/oracle/
RUN unzip /opt/oracle/instantclient*.zip -d /opt/oracle/ && rm /opt/oracle/instantclient*.zip
RUN echo temp=$(find /opt/oracle -name "instantclient*")
ENV ORACLE_DRIVER_PATH=$temp

But this way the variable ORACLE_DRIVER_PATH results empty: if I run sudo docker exec <container_id> env I see ORACLE_DRIVER_PATH=.
What am I missing? I would expect to see /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_13.
The value needs to be dynamic because it might change.

temp is not set as a environment variable, so the ENV block will never set the right value.

Try something like this (not tested): RUN echo "ORACLE_DRIVER_PATH=$(find /opt/oracle -name 'instantclient*')" >> /etc/environment and delete the last ENV instruction

@RuiJarimba Most paths to running commands in Docker, including the standard CMD, don't read /etc/environment or other shell dotfiles, and it's not usually right to try to change those files.  This isn't easy to do, and a better practice might be to pick a specific version of the client library (maybe as a Dockerfile ARG).

You can't set ENV to the result of a command, and RUN export doesn't last beyond the current RUN instruction.  In general, the pattern of what you're trying to do is hard.
Since you expect that there's only going to be a single version of the library in the image, one thing you can do is to use a RUN instruction to rename it to a fixed path.  Then you can use that fixed path in a Dockerfile ENV directive.
RUN cd /opt/oracle \
  && unzip instantclient*.zip \
  && rm instantclient*.zip \
  && mv instantclient* instantclient
ENV ORACLE_DRIVER_PATH /opt/oracle/instantclient

It looks like the URL you're downloading produces a variable version, and so your image might have different libraries and different behavior depending on when it's built.  If there's a download URL that provides a fixed version, you could specify the version number as a build-time ARG, and now you'll know a fixed path every place you need it.
ARG ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_VERSION=21_13
RUN wget https://???/instantclient-basiclite-${ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_VERSION}-linuxx64.zip -P /opt/oracle/
RUN cd /opt/oracle \
  && unzip instantclient-basiclite-${ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_VERSION}-linuxx64.zip \
  && rm instantclient-basiclite-${ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_VERSION}-linuxx64.zip
ENV ORACLE_DRIVER_PATH /opt/oracle/instantclient_${ORACLE_INSTANTCLIENT_VERSION}


I'll try that, thank you. For starters, it was something that actually bothered me, not being able to fix the client version. This seems to me a viable solution (and it works).
